# Cannot wrap divs correctly with nextUntil()

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML. I have tried the following, but I can't wrap the elements correctly.

```js
$('.cards .card-image').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".card-description").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='card'></div>");
});
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <img class="card-image" src="...">
  <img class="card-image" src="...">
  <img class="card-image" src="...">
  <div class="card-description">
    <p>First image description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <p>Second image description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <p>Third image description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to wrap the image with its corresponding description into a div like this:

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="...">
    <div class="card-description">
      <p>First image description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="...">
    <div class="card-description">
      <p>Second image description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="...">
    <div class="card-description">
      <p>Third image description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `nextUntil()` won't work in this case as the `.card-image` and `card-description` elements are not adjacent siblings.

To work around this you can instead loop through all the `.card-image` elements, appending them to a new `.card` div along with the relevant `.card-description` which matches the index of the current image. Try this:

```js
let $cards = $('.cards');
let $descriptions = $('.card-description');
$cards.children('.card-image').each(function(i) {
  let $card = $('<div class="card" />').appendTo($cards);
  $card.append(this, $descriptions.eq(i));
});
```

```css
.card { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <img class="card-image" src="..." />
  <img class="card-image" src="..." />
  <img class="card-image" src="..." />
  <div class="card-description">
    <p>First image description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <p>Second image description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-description">
    <p>Third image description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, note that `<img />` elements do not have a closing `</img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `.card-description` div is not following the `img`, you cannot really use `nextUntil()`.

Instead you can loop over the images and wrap them together with their matching description, e.g.:

```js
const $cardImages = $('.cards .card-image');
const $cardDescriptions = $('.cards .card-description');

$cardImages.each(function(index, card) {
  const $card = $(card);
  $card.wrap('<div class="card"></div>');
  const $description = $cardDescriptions.eq(index);
  $description.detach().insertAfter($card);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <img class="card-image" src="..."></img>
  <img class="card-image" src="..."></img>
  <img class="card-image" src="..."></img>
  <div class="card-description"><p>First image description</p></div>
  <div class="card-description"><p>Second image description</p></div>
  <div class="card-description"><p>Third image description</p></div>
</div>
```